# How to find similar noun phrases in NLP?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, synonym, named-entity-recognition, pattern-synonyms

Is there a way to identify similar noun phrases. Some suggest use pattern-based approaches, for example `X as Y` expressions:

> Usain Bolt as Sprint King
>
> Liverpool as Reds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many techniques to find alternative names for a given entity,
using patterns such as:

- `X also known as Y`
- `X also titled as Y`

and scanning large collections of documents (e.g., Wikipedia or news papers articles) is one way to do it.

There are also other alternatives, one I remember is using Wikipedia inter-links structure, for instance, by exploring the redirect links between articles. You can download a file with a list of redirects from here: https://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-04 and exploring the file you can find alternative names/synonyms for entities, e.g.:

- `Kennedy_Centre -> John_F._Kennedy_Center_for_the_Performing_Arts>`
- `Lord_Alton_of_Liverpool -> David_Alton,_Baron_Alton_of_Liverpool`
- `Indiana_jones_2 -> Indiana_Jones_and_the_Temple_of_Doom`

Another thing you can do is combine these two techniques, for instance, look for text segments where both `Indiana Jones` and `Indiana_Jones_and_the_Temple_of_Doom` occur and are not further apart more than, let's say, 4 or 5 tokens. You might find patterns like `also titled as`, then you can use these patterns to find more synonyms/alternative names.

Comment: Is it possible to use pattern approach in twitter or facebook post collection like retrieving data similar to keyword and search through the collection.

Comment: The patterns you mention above are known as "Hearst Patterns". A paper that automatically finds and evaluates similar patterns is "Learning syntactic patterns for automatic hypernym discovery" - traditionally these patterns were for finding hypernyms, but with a little change they work for synonyms too. https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2659-learning-syntactic-patterns-for-automatic-hypernym-discovery